# i lost my shortcut to sql server management studio - where to find it?

Tags: sql-server-2008

i lost my shortcut to sql server management studio - where to find it ?

what is the EXE name ?

thanks in advance

Comment: `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWb.exe"` For SQL Server 2005, don't know if its the standard path but i guess so.

Comment: sqlwb.exe, but that's a windows issue. This forum is for developer issues.

Comment: Why did 19 people upvote this?

Answer (score 36):

type **SqlWb** command in run window to open sql server (for sql server 2005).

type **ssms** command in run window to open sql server (for sql server 2008).

Comment: For more recent versions of SQL Server Management Studio have a hunt for the following (changing "110" as required): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\ssms.exe